# How do I get an AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater from a scala companion object?

Tags: scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

If I have a linked node in some collection structure I don't really want its next link to be an AtomicReference (I need atomic CAS update) so I declare it as:

```
@volatile var next: Node[A] = _n
```

and then in the companion declare:

```
val updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(classOf[Link[_]], classOf[Node[_]], "n")
def cas[A](target: Link[A], old: Node[A], newNode: Node[A]) = updater.compareAndSet(target, old, newNode);
```

At runtime I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
  Class concurrent.Link$ can not access a member of class concurrent.Link
  with modifiers "private volatile"
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:65)
    at concurrent.Link$.<init>(Link.scala:106)
    ...
```

So, at runtime the companion object is `concurrent.Link$` not `concurrent.Link` and a different class cannot access the private member of another.

BUT, if I `javap -p concurrent.Link`

I get:

```
Compiled from "Link.scala"
public final class concurrent.Link implements concurrent.Node,scala.ScalaObject,scala.Product,java.io.Serializable{
private final java.lang.Object value;
private volatile com.atlassian.util.scala.concurrent.Node node;
public static final boolean cas(com.atlassian.util.scala.concurrent.Link, com.atlassian.util.scala.concurrent.Node, com.atlassian.util.scala.concurrent.Node);
public static final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater updater();
```

So, I have everything but the static instance of the `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` declared on my `Link` class.

The question is, how do I get an instance of `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` in Scala that points to a volatile var?

The only way I've found so far is to go back to Java (implement an AbstractLink with the next Node field and a static `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater`) and inherit from that, which is ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told there is no way to do this in pure scala, and you need to define a class in Java to do this. Fortunately cross-compilation is pretty simple, but still, annoying!

Answer (score 4):

Hard. Since Scala makes fields private, and only accessor methods available, this might not be possible.

When doing this, I eventually decided to do it by creating Java base class with the volatile field and updating through there.

Java file:

```
public class Base {
   volatile Object field = null;
}
```

Scala file:

```
class Cls extends Base {
  val updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(classOf[Base[_]], classOf[Object[_]], "field")
  def cas[A](old: Object, n: Object) = updater.compareAndSet(this, old, n);
}
```

I haven't come up with a different approach.

Comment: thanks @axel22, I already have the ugly Java hack (see last line of the question) so I can't give this as an answer.

Comment: actually, I reread your solution and it misses out an important property of the AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater and that is that it is static. You want to share the same updater among all instances, that's the point – otherwise you just use an AtomicReference directly.

Comment: This is a topic for discussion - it might actually be cheaper to have it as a private field than as a static reference, and one would have to benchmark this. It should be cheaper than having it inside a companion object in any case.

Comment: in terms of memory it would definitely be cheaper having the static. Each node would cause only one object creation rather than two, so it is hard to see how the private would be cheaper.

Comment: Cheaper in terms of the time needed to invoke the cas. You only create an object once, but usually access it many times. Putting the updater inside a companion object would mean that to access it, you need to fetch the companion object reference first, and then invoke the getter on it to get the updater. Having a private field amounts to one indirection. This can cost you one cache miss less. And you can always instantiate the updater once, and put the reference to it in all `Cls` objects. Still, I would do a microbenchmark to verify this assumption.

Comment: @axel22 If you look at the `javap` output above, you'll see that the reference is compiled statically into the Link class by scalac, so it should already be loaded – which is one of the reasons this is so frustrating!